# Generate Input for a different application

Tags: java, testing

I need to programmatically generate a mouseclick within Java code for a different application running on the same Win7 machine. The process is already known (Pointer to Process). Is there an API or an application that I can use for this?

This is needed for the GUI part of a custom made testing framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.awt.Robot` class is your friend. You can generate mouse and keyboard input with it.

Look at [this tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/54172-robot-class/).

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)